# Cross Browser input field width stylization

Tags: input, cross-browser, styling

I have a shipping/billing input form and I'm having trouble styling the input fields to be the same width...

The Problem:
-a field `<input type="text" size="X" />` appears to render with different sizes in different browsers (see [link](http://tryboda.com/index.php)).
-In addition, select fields seem to render on a differently as well.
-Chrome/safari do not seem to respond to the font-size property for select fields.

Any guidance on how to stylize the size of text-input and select fields cross-browser would be oh so very helpful.

Must I result to having a different sytlesheet for each browser... just for these input fields?
-thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove that inline "size" attribute, first. You should use CSS to style the input form:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100px;

    /* You can also style padding, margins and everything else,
     * just remember that inputs of type "text" can only be one line. 
     */
}
```

Don't use [type="text"] as a selector. I was just using it in this example to associate with input fields of type "text", but it's not fully cross-browser supported. You should give your text input fields their own class to stylize with.

Also, don't forget your CSS reset to make sure your margins, borders, et. al. are reset for all browsers. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Actually, using the eric meyer reset, and styling the width using css as you explained, not all input fields have the same widths when comparing webkit to IE7 -> IE9

Comment: In my experience, them's the breaks. There's a lot of goofy inconsistencies with the box model, for instance: how to fit an input field into 100% the width of its parent box. Normally, you'd achieve this by setting the parent box to 100% width, then setting the margin or padding parameters of the inside box, but since input fields are self-contained, there's no way to create, in any platform, a way to consistently tie a text box's width to its parent container (not that the other method is clean or semantical). Ideally, boxes and fields should have an outsideWidth definition.

Comment: This answer does not provide consistent sizing of input boxes. It has some valuable information, but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, it's possible to normalize the width of "sized" inputs, using the [ch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Font-relative_lengths) unit, which has reached a decent browser support.

Unfortunately, it's still not possible to write:

```
input[size] {
  width: attr(size) "ch";
}
```

So we have to style the widths we *know* we'll be using:

```
input[size="10"] {width: 10ch;}
input[size="20"] {width: 20ch;}
input[size="30"] {width: 30ch;}
/* etc. */
```

This can easily be automated using a CSS preprocessor.

**UPDATE:**

I made a [test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bujr1d94/1/). As of today (feb. 2018), this is working on Windows 10 with Chrome 63, Edge 41, FF 58. On IE 11, it fails. I haven't tried on OS X.

Comment: Too bad "ch" doesn't actually work for input size. E.g. with a monospace font, in order to get an input box that shows 30 chars, on IE I have to set 37ch, and on Chrome 33ch. Makes it pretty much useless in my opinion.

Comment: I made a [test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bujr1d94/1/). On Windows 10, this is working with Chrome 63, Edge 41, FF 58. On IE 11, it fails. I haven't tried on OS X.